# input type="file" not populating canvas on android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, input-type-file

I trying to build a web app using html5 which has a user profile page and I am having an issue with input type="file" when testing it on an Android browser. When selected it gives me the option to open camera or gallery, when an file is selected, it populates the file field, but I can't get the file to populate the canvas. This is working perfectly on ios and firefox, chrome on Android.

Here is the html code:

```
    <canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="120" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="takePictureField" onchange="picChange(event)">
```

And the JavaScript:

function picChange(evt)
{
    var fileInput = evt.target.files;

```
if(fileInput.length>0)
{
    var windowURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var picURL = windowURL.createObjectURL(fileInput[0]);
    var photoCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = photoCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var photo = new Image();

    photo.onload = function()
    {
        ctx.drawImage(photo, 0, 0, 160, 120);
    };
photo.src = picURL;
windowURL.revokeObjectURL(picURL);
}
```

}

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?? Do I need to add something to the windowURL so that Android can recognize it?? Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is really starting to bug me!!

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to the latest version of andriod seemed to fix this!